# R.java file doesn't allow creation of new folder in the project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, windows-7, r.java-file

I have been trying to create a folder manually to keep all the styling xml files inside my android project using eclipse in windows 7. As soon as I create a xml file inside that new folder and save the xml file. My R.java goes missing. I understand that R.java is not taking in the manual changes to the project. I believe there is a way we can make changes to the project by manually adding folders and reflecting the changes to the R.java file accordingly.

So can anyone please help me out as to what do I have to do to allow manual changes in my project as described above?

Comment: what's the name of the folder you are creating ?  FYI not any name is accepted

Comment: @user2427819 Ok, this is interesting... I am quite new to android development so don't know the rules of naming folders while creating it.. Please let me know or give me the link which describes the names I can give to the folders I manually create in an android app project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way you can create a `styles` xml file, is inside a `values` folder, so you can't assemble all the `styles` files inside one folder, android will not recognize it, thus, not allowing what you are trying to do

here is a link to follow when creating a folder,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

check this part within `Table 1. Resource directories supported inside project res/ directory.`

Comment: So is there any convention on naming the folders I create in android, because I solved my problem by creating a folder named "drawable" instead of "style"?

Comment: it will work because drawable is a valid name, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Styling XML files should go someone in your RES folder, typically some flavor of "values" (like just "values" or "values-hdpi", etc.)

Putting them somewhere else can cause errors, usually they just can't be used but also could cause Eclipse to not be able to build the R.java file correctly.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I did put the new folder inside res folder its just that I named it "style". What is the exact reason I can't name the folders as to what I want?